# How to loop through multiple different urls while web scraping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I spend the whole day investigating the internet for my question but I couldn't find any solution, so, therefore, I address my issue to you:

I successfully wrote a code to scrape a specific URL for certain information. Now I want to enhance the code to scrape multiple URLs for the same information.

- The website URL differs by a single word at the end of the text. I wrote a code to build a list of the URLs. For this example, I cut it down to two websites (changingignwordinurl).
- I want to scrape the data of "Name", "Balls touched", and "Yellow Cards" of the two websites where

  ```
   - the name can be found on both websites
   - the amount of balls touched can be found on (changingignwordinurl = ballkontakte) and 
   - the amount of yellow cards can be found on the second website (changingignwordinurl = fairplay)
  ```
- My goal is to have a list of all player names and their amount of balls touched, and underneath that all players that have a yellow card and the amount of that

Can anyone of you pros identify my mistake(s)? Your help is very much appreciated :).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

urllist = []
changingignwordinurl = ["-ballkontakte/","-fairplay/",]
rooturl = "https://sportdaten.spiegel.de/fussball/bundesliga/ma9417803/fc-augsburg_eintracht-frankfurt/spielstatistik"

for word in changingignwordinurl:
    urllist.append(rooturl+word)

playerdata = []

for url in urllist:
    def get_data(url):
        response = requests.get(urllist)            
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"lxml")

        players = soup.find("table", 
                class_="module-statistics statistics")

        for player in players:
            item={}

            name = player.find("td", class_="person-name")
            ballstouchedtotal = player.find("td", class_="person_stats-balls_touched person_stats-balls_touched-list")
            yellowcards = player.find("td", class_= "person_stats-card_yellow person_stats-card_yellow-list")

            item["Name"] = name.text.strip() if name else ""
            item["Balls touched"] = ballstouchedtotal.text.strip() if ballstouchedtotal else ""
            item["Yellow Card"] = yellowcards.text.strip() if yellowcards else ""
                
            data.append(item)

        return playerdata 

print(playerdata)
```

Comment: `data.append(item)` should be `playerdata.append(item)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my solution.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_data(url):
    data = []
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    # This checks if the request FAIL, if fails then return empty data
    if(not response.ok):
        print(f"Conection to {url} FAIL")
        return data

    print(f"Conection to {url} OK")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")

    players = soup.find("table",
            class_="module-statistics statistics")
    
    for player in players:
        item={}

        name = player.find("td", class_="person-name")
        ballstouchedtotal = player.find("td", class_="person_stats-balls_touched person_stats-balls_touched-list")
        yellowcards = player.find("td", class_= "person_stats-card_yellow person_stats-card_yellow-list")

        item["Name"] = name.text.strip() if name else ""
        item["Balls touched"] = ballstouchedtotal.text.strip() if ballstouchedtotal else ""
        item["Yellow Card"] = yellowcards.text.strip() if yellowcards else ""

        data.append(item)
    
    return data

urllist = []
changingignwordinurl = ["-ballkontakte/","-fairplay/",]
rooturl = "https://sportdaten.spiegel.de/fussball/bundesliga/ma9417803/fc-augsburg_eintracht-frankfurt/spielstatistik"

# Get URLs
for word in changingignwordinurl:
    urllist.append(rooturl+word)

playerdata = []

# Get data for each URL
for url in urllist:
    playerdata.append(get_data(url))

print(playerdata)
```

EDIT: Sorry for being unclear, it was my fist answer ever , also I was writting the answer when @noelle-l answered so I didn't notice that the question was answered. The only difference to @noelle-l answer is the little If statement that checks if the request was OK or not, the rest is just almost indentical.

Comment: How is this different from the answer by @noelle-l?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @JonSG sorry, I just make an edit being more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the function `get_data()`, but it isn't being called. Consider moving the function definition out of the loop and replacing it with a function call `get_data(url)`.

Try something more like:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url)            
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser") ## "xlml" also valid if you install it
    players = soup.find("table", class_="module-statistics statistics")
    this_url_player_data = []
    for player in players:
        item={}

        name = player.find("td", class_="person-name")
        ballstouchedtotal = player.find("td", class_="person_stats-balls_touched person_stats-balls_touched-list")
        yellowcards = player.find("td", class_= "person_stats-card_yellow person_stats-card_yellow-list")

        item["Name"] = name.text.strip() if name else ""
        item["Balls touched"] = ballstouchedtotal.text.strip() if ballstouchedtotal else ""
        item["Yellow Card"] = yellowcards.text.strip() if yellowcards else ""
            
        this_url_player_data.append(item)
    return this_url_player_data 

rooturl = "https://sportdaten.spiegel.de/fussball/bundesliga/ma9417803/fc-augsburg_eintracht-frankfurt/spielstatistik"
changingignwordinurl = ["-ballkontakte/","-fairplay/",]
urllist = []
for word in changingignwordinurl:
    urllist.append(rooturl+word)

playerdata = []
for url in urllist:
    playerdata += get_data(url)

print(playerdata)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I moved it outside the for url in urllist loop but unfortunately it does not work. I anticipate the problem to be that the loop cannot recall the created urls properly.

Comment: Thanks for the indication. I updated data to playerdata but it does not solve the problem unfortunately. I receive the error message: _InvalidSchema(f"No connection adapters were found for {url!r}"_

Comment: That message was because you were calling `requests.get(urllist)` rather than `requests.get(url)`. The edit just now has a complete example that returns a result

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! You are the real heros :D